# View/Edit html form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, webforms

I have a form thats displays data, i want it to behave as an html form as well, when user clicks 'Edit' the fields would become editable and on save the form will be submitted. any pointers to the implementation?

Comment: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/custom.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$(document).ready({
    var span_field = ".spn_data"
    var btn_edit = "#btnedit"
    var btn_save = "#btnsave"

    $(btn_edit).click(function(){
        $(span_field).each(function(){
            $(this).replaceWith("<input type='text' value='" + $(this).html() + "' class='spn_data' />");
        });
    });

    $(btn_save).click(function(){
        $(span_field).each(function(){
            $(this).replaceWith("<span  class='spn_data'>" + $(this).val() + "'</span>");
        });
        // do save
    });


});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you could set the form elements to disabled and overwrite the standard styling so that it still would look normal.